# filling and renaming a dataset at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, enumerate

i would like to filling a dataset and making the log returns at the same time:
These are the returns

```
ret_names  =['FTSEMIB_Index_ret', 'FCA_IM_Equity_ret', 'UCG_IM_Equity_ret', 'ISP_IM_Equity_ret',
 'ENI_IM_Equity_ret',
 'LUX_IM_Equity_ret']
```

and this is the Dataframe

```
   'FTSEMIB_Index', 'FCA_IM_Equity', 'UCG_IM_Equity', 'ISP_IM_Equity','ENI_IM_Equity', 'LUX_IM_Equity'                                                                 
0   22793.69        14.840                16.430           2.8860        14.040            49.24
1   22991.99        15.150                16.460           2.8780        14.220            48.98
2   23046.05        15.290                16.760           2.8660        14.300            48.70
3   23014.13        15.660                16.390           2.8500        14.380            48.72
4   23002.85        15.590                16.300           2.8420        14.500            49.13
```

so my idea is to use `enumerate` in a for loop.

```
for index,name in enumerate(ret_names):
    df[name] = np.diff(np.log(df.iloc[:,index]))
```

but i cannot match the lenght because having the returns i'm going to erase 1 value (the first one i suppose).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

maybe i found a solution, but i can't figure out why the previous one doesn't work

```
for index,name in enumerate(ret_names):
    df[name] = np.log(df.iloc[:,index])/np.log(df.iloc[:,index]).shift(1)
```

with this you can fill and assign name, and the first value will increase.